# Jquery - customize ui.ja

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, plugins

I am using jquery´s "ui.js" and "ui.css".

When i have this snippet:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Everything works fine, but when user chooses one item, i want to fire an event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input#tags').on('change', function() {
      alert("event")
    });
});
```

It doesnt work, anybody knows how to fire event´s when user select´s item?

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine as-is:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Vnhd8/

Couple of notes...

- As you are using `change` and not `keyup` you need to leave the field for it to fire the event.
- The modern/preferred onload syntax is simply `$(function{...});`
- As id's are supposed to be unique on a page, and are the fastest lookup method, adding an `input` selector before the id may actually slow down the search.

### Neater version

```
$(function () {
    $('#tags').on('change', function() {
      alert("event")
    });
});
```

If you were to allow for dynamically created elements, use the deferred syntax of `on` applied to an element that does not change (and is an ancestor of the target):

### Deferred "on" version:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('change', '#tags', function() {
      alert("event")
    });
});
```

### If you want per-keypress events instead:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Vnhd8/4/

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('keyup', '#tags', function() {
      alert('event');
    });
});
```

*Only the last JSFiddle above uses jQueryUI (just to make sure it made no different to the events).*